# Dynanically set color of text based on first letter in that text

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I want to make function that sets color of text based on first letter in that text.
I was looking for some solution for a while and couldnt find anything and dont know if it's even possible.

Here's what i want to achieve:

There's `<h1>` tag that is dynamically generated on multiple locations.

I wanto to achieve that for example if this text starts with A,B,C or D color is set to red
If it starts with E,F,G or H color is set to green etc for different letter and color combinations..

So for example `<h1 class="dynamic-color">Alphabet</h1>` and `<h1 class="dynamic-color">Banana</h1>` will be red

And `<h1 class="dynamic-color">Fireman</h1>` and `<h1 class="dynamic-color">Grass</h1>` will be green.

Is something like this even possible?

Comment: You tagged your question with both PHP and Javascript so this is unclear what do you mean by *dynamically*. Do you mean filling your h1 with text taken from a database? Do you generate that on the client or server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here i've made a little example using jQuery: https://jsfiddle.net/Taki7o7/c26ny3bj/

```js
$('.dynamic-color').each(function(){ // For each element with class "dynamic-color"
  
  // Trim text & get the first character in lower case
  let firstChar = $(this).text().trim().charAt(0).toLowerCase();
  
  
  // Your conditions
  
  if(firstChar == 'a' || firstChar == 'b'){ // starting with a or b
    // Set color to red
      $(this).css('color', 'red');
  }
  else if(firstChar == 's'){ // starting with s
    // Set color to green
      $(this).css('color', 'green');
  }
  
  // You can add as many else if blocks as you want for more options
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1 class="dynamic-color">

Apple
</h1> <!-- thats why we better trim() -->

<h1 class="dynamic-color">Banana</h1>
<h1 class="dynamic-color">Strawberry</h1>
<h1 class="dynamic-color">Mango</h1>
```

This example makes h1 tags with dynamic-color class beginning with A or B (case not matter) red, h1 beginning with S green, and does not do anything if none of them.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what i was looking for !

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is by having a pair of letters and colors.

```
<h1 class="dynamic-color">Apple</h1>
<h1 class="dynamic-color">Banana</h1>
<h1 class="dynamic-color">Cardigan</h1>
```

```
$(function(){
    const list = {'a': '#ff0', 'b': '#eee', 'c': '#111'}
    const $el = $('.dynamic-color')
    // iterate every element that has the class .dynamic-color
    $.each($el, function () {
        const $this = $(this)
        // get the first letter
        const firstLetter = $this.text().trim().charAt(0).toLowerCase()
        // check if firstletter is a property of the list
        if(list.hasOwnProperty(firstLetter)) {
           // if the property exist, get the corresponding color.
           $this.css({
               'color' : list[firstLetter]
           })
        }   
    })
})
```

```html
<h1 class="dynamic-color">Apple</h1>
<h1 class="dynamic-color">Banana</h1>
<h1 class="dynamic-color">Cardigan</h1>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
  const list = {
    'a': '#ff0',
    'b': '#eee',
    'c': '#111'
  }
  const $el = $('.dynamic-color')

  $.each($el, function() {
    const $this = $(this)
    const firstLetter = $this.text().trim().charAt(0).toLowerCase()
    if (list.hasOwnProperty(firstLetter)) {
      $this.css({
        'color': list[firstLetter]
      })
    }
  })
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Vanilla JS:

You can create an object with the colors as keys and the first character as an array nested in the color.

Then pass a different obj of words (***array, nodeList, HTML collection, object, single string, etc***) into a function and using a for iteration loop, create a variable that will be the matching character to check. Use `el.charAt(0).toLowerCase`, to get the character at the beginning and then cast it to lowercase. Then run your color obj through a `for in` loop and check if each color array includes the matching variable.

If so, change the color of the word to its rgb value set as a key in our color obj.

In my example I use a function that gets the values from a nodeList, and another that gets values from an array.

```js
const alpha = {
  "rgb(255,0,0)": ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
  "rgb(0,85,255)": ["e", "f", "g", "h"],
  "rgb(0,255,0)": ["i", "j", "k", "l"],
  "rgb(255,255,50)": ["m", "n", "o", "p"],
  "rgb(255,128,0)": ["q", "r", "s", "t"],
  "rgb(179,25,255)": ["u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
}

const arrayOfHeadings = ["Zeta", "Frank", "Jack", "Meta", "Sierra", "Alpha"]

const divs = document.querySelectorAll('.divs')

function getColorFromNodeList(obj) {
  for (let i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    let match = obj[i].textContent.trim().charAt(0).toLowerCase();
    for (let key in alpha) {
      if (alpha[key].includes(match)) {
        obj[i].style.color = key
      }
    }
  }
}

function getColorFromObject(obj) {
  for (let i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    let match = obj[i].charAt(0).toLowerCase();
    for (let key in alpha) {
      if (alpha[key].includes(match)) {
        display.innerHTML += `<div class='divs' style='color: ${key}'>${obj[i]}</div>`
      }
    }
  }
}

getColorFromNodeList(divs)
getColorFromObject(arrayOfHeadings)
```

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 100vw;
}

.divs {
  width: 60px;
}

.cont {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="cont">
    <div class="divs"> Apple </div>
    <div class="divs">Cat</div>
    <div class="divs">Dog</div>
    <div class="divs">People</div>
    <div class="divs">Horse</div>
    <div class="divs">Zumba</div>
    <div class="divs">Query</div>
    <div class="divs">Infant</div>
    <div class="divs">Snack</div>
    <div class="divs">Virgo</div>
    <div class="divs">Ground</div>
  </div>

  <div id="display"></div>
</div>
```